# List<WebElement>.get(i).click picking up random elements

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of images and each need to be clicked. 
Below is the **HTML**

```
<div id="VELayerListDiv">
<div id="msftve_1002">
    <a id="msftve_1002_200000_10000" class="VEAPI_Pushpin" href="javascript://pushin hover" style="position: absolute; left: -17px; top: 450px; display: block; z-index: 1000;">
        <div onmousedown="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmousedown"))return;VEDragVEShapeDown("msftve_1002_200000_10000",1429800443062);" onmouseover="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmouseover"))return;VEShowVEShapeERO("msftve_1002_200000_10000",1429800443062);" onmouseout="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmouseout"))return;VEHideVEShapeERO(false);">
            <div style="position:absolute;left:6.5px;top:-2px;writing-mode:tb-rl;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=0, xray=0, mirror=0, invert=0, opacity=1, rotation=0);opacity:1;">
                <img width="17" height="34" src="images/spatial/custout_50-499_U2.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="msftve_1003">
    <a id="msftve_1003_200003_10003" class="VEAPI_Pushpin" href="javascript://pushin hover" style="position: absolute; left: 278.5px; top: 363.5px; display: block; z-index: 1000;">
        <div onmousedown="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmousedown"))return;VEDragVEShapeDown("msftve_1003_200003_10003",1429800443062);" onmouseover="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmouseover"))return;VEShowVEShapeERO("msftve_1003_200003_10003",1429800443062);" onmouseout="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmouseout"))return;VEHideVEShapeERO(false);">
            <div style="position:absolute;left:6.5px;top:-2px;writing-mode:tb-rl;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=0, xray=0, mirror=0, invert=0, opacity=1, rotation=0);opacity:1;">
                <img width="17" height="34" src="images/spatial/custout_2-49_U2.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a id="msftve_1003_200004_10004" class="VEAPI_Pushpin" href="javascript://pushin hover" style="position: absolute; left: 277.5px; top: 362.5px; display: block; z-index: 1000;">
        <div onmousedown="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmousedown"))return;VEDragVEShapeDown("msftve_1003_200004_10004",1429800443062);" onmouseover="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmouseover"))return;VEShowVEShapeERO("msftve_1003_200004_10004",1429800443062);" onmouseout="if (VEMap._GetMapFromGUID(1429800443062).FireEvent("onmouseout"))return;VEHideVEShapeERO(false);">
            <div style="position:absolute;left:6.5px;top:-2px;writing-mode:tb-rl;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=0, xray=0, mirror=0, invert=0, opacity=1, rotation=0);opacity:1;">
                <img width="17" height="34" src="images/spatial/custout_2-49_U2.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have written the following code:

```
List<WebElement> pins = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='VELayerListDiv']/div/a/div/div/img")));
        System.out.println("Total Pins :"+pins.size());
        for(int x=0;x<pins.size();x++)
        {           
            pins.get(x).click();
        }
```

The above code clicks the pins randomly. It is not clicking all the Pins uniquely (i.e all imgs). I get click on img1,img2,img1,img3,img1

I am not sure what is wrong as I get all the img's in the list (as `pins.size()` is correct). But the click does not click every img uniquely.

It is something to do with `img` tag not having any unique identifier.

Comment: How many webelements are in the list?  The HTML isn't the same for the two div objects within the top div element.  Also, use a var pinSize = pins.Size(); instead of calling it Size each time.  Have you tried By.xpath("//img") ?  Might not work if your page has a lot of images.

Comment: there are 34 imgs which I am able to get the list. If I do a size of the list  get 34 which is correct. My problem is if I iterate the list and click on each webelement it is actually clicking elements at random . Is it because the img tag does not have any other attribute for selenium to identify(though I think selenium should index the img tag by itself)

Comment: Why not use `By.tagName("img")` and then use `getAttribute("width=17")` just to ensure you are selecting only those img tags given in the html?

Comment: @AshutoshBarawkar - I think you have a valid assessment of the behavior.  If there isn't anything unique about the images, Selenium may not know which to select.  In your example HTML, the 2nd and 3rd img elements are identical.  The 1st is different.  I would think Selenium would always click on the same img element for those that are identical.

Comment: @MikeWeber - I think I know what the problem is... The "img" is is on a map and are sometime cluttered together one upon other. The questions is .. Does selenium click on the img tag on html or specific location i.e if the pins are overlapping will this problem arise

Comment: @AshutoshBarawkar did you find any solution to this?